# Adobe Reader 11 and a JavaScript error in IE11

Tags: javascript, adobe-reader, windows-server-2012-r2, internet-explorer-11

I get a javascript "Script Error" popup window every time when it tries to auto open this page. The page contains adobe pdf files, and the script opens the pdf automatically inside the webpage/window.

I have done the following, Open Internet Explorer browser....

> **Turn off script debugging and notifications in Internet Explorer**
>
> Script error debugging and notifications are turned off by default. If
>   they have been turned on, follow these steps to turn them off again.
>
> Open Internet Explorer by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>   Start button. In the search box, type Internet Explorer, and then, in
>   the list of results, click Internet Explorer.
>
> Click the Tools button, and then click Internet Options.
>
> Click the Advanced tab, select the **Disable script debugging Internet**
>   **Explorer)** and **Disable script debugging (Other)** check boxes.
>
> Clear the **Display a notification about every script error** check box,
>   and then click OK.

I have also added the sites to "Trusted", and even lowered all security settings to the minimum. And disabled Protected Mode.

[image]

The problem still persists.

**EDIT**: This error is related to Adobe Reader security protection

Open Adobe Reader and go to ***Edit > Preferences > General***.

In the Application Startup panel, check or uncheck **Enable Protected Mode at startup**.

> In the registry and find this key:
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\Privileged]
>   "bProtectedMode"=(0 = off; 1 = on)

More information can be found at the [Adobe websit](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/protectedmode.html)e.
Protected Mode

```
Evolution of Protected Mode
Version Change
10.0    Protected Mode introduced in Reader.
10.x-11.0   Many changes and improvement were made for dot releases as described at http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/protected-mode-troubleshooting-reader.html
11.0    See Read policy changes for 11.0
```

Comment: What's the actual error it's reporting? If it's only a specific page (or site), then to me it sounds like it's probably a problem on their end. Have you spoken to the site's owners? Have you tried it form another computer with IE11? Have you tried it from your computer with all IE add-ons disabled?

Comment: I have added a picture of the error, and added information (EDIT2).

Comment: added information (EDIT3)

Comment: Logman, if you have no addons and have tried another browser it is most defiantly a problem on the site owners side.